# read one Line in textfile and use it as variablein PHP

Tags: php

Hello everyone I'm facing this problem two days now and I need your help.

I want to use proxy in my php curlopt via array and one proxy will be used five times before proceeding to the next proxy.

The only thing I know based on google searchers over two pages are:

```
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to an array
if ($fp) {
   $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}
```

But when I echo the array it shows all proxies in the textfile and not just one which results to not reading in the curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $poxySocks4);
```

Is there any way to use one proxy five times then proceed to another? Please help me.

Edited: Here is the full code:

```
function binsforeveryoneproxys()
{ 
$fileName='joestar.txt'; //textfile
$proxies = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  foreach ( $proxies as $proxy )  {
    echo $proxy; 
    return  $proxies; 
}
}
$saitama= binsforeveryoneproxys();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $saitama);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, getcwd().'/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
'accept: application/json',
'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'origin: ',
'referer: '
)); 

//////////////////////////// POSTFIELD 1 ////////////////////////// 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file()` which will read in the list of lines in the file into separate lines of the array.  This saves having to open/read/split the file.

Then use a `foreach()` over this list with a `for()` loop to do the repeating part...

```
$proxies = file( $fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ( $proxies as $proxy )  {
    echo $proxy.PHP_EOL;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )    {
        // .....
    }
}
```

Comment: So i will put inside the for() part the whole curl_setop ? or just put curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxies); inside the for loop? Sorry im very new.

Comment: You can put the whole curl code  inside the loop, try it and see if you have problems.

Comment: Update: I tried doing it and it ends up displaying all proxies inside the text. I tried putting the curl curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); inside the loop. And when I tried to put all the curl inside the loop it doesn't work as well, its not working :<

Comment: It would help if you added some more details - it's not working doesn't help.  It will go through all of the proxies, but it will do the inside loop 5 times for each proxy.  Does the curl work on it's own?

Comment: This is how my code works, I will put  ten websites in a box where a user will check if its working or not. To check those inserted websites, There is an API used so that it checks. Now, the API has a lookup site in a curl Post code and I want to use proxies inside the text file "proxy,txt". I tried your code and it shows all proxies in my textfile. I want to pick one Proxy and use it five times before proceeding to another proxy. I tried all putting the curls into the loop and it only shows white page which I repeatedly refreshed and My proxies are High Quality (Tested twice).

Comment: I've said it will show all the proxies, but use 1 at a time in the loop.

Comment: Update: It works now but it only reads the first proxy line in my text file.Sorry for my low Comprehension I'm very new. I tried removing the for loop first so that you can give me hints what to do next. $fileName='joestar.txt';
$proxies = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  foreach ( $proxies as $proxy )  {
    echo $proxy.PHP_EOL;

Comment: Can you add your code to the original question (add it, don't replace the original code).

Comment: I added up the code above and I echoed $saitama, it shows a plain text "Array" not a proxy number :<